# Cassandra Delete setting non-key fields to null

Tags: java, database, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

We are running batched delete statements on 5 tables using datastax java driver. We noticed that on some occasions, the record doesn't get deleted from one of the tables, instead the non-key fields are being set to null.

We have been using the key columns on this table to do a duplicate check, so when we use the same values to create a new record with the same values, it fails our duplicate check.

IS this expected behavior? if yes, can we override it to be able to physically delete the row(expected behavior) as part o our batch execution?

Also, why is it always happening with just 1(always the same table) out of total 5.

```
Table definition:CREATE TABLE customer_ks.customer_by_accountnumber (
customerid text,
accountnumber text,
accounttype text,
age int,
name text,
PRIMARY KEY (customerid, accountnumber))
```

and here is the query I run on this table as part of the batch:

DELETE FROM customer_by_accountnumber WHERE customerid=? AND accountnumber=?
along with deletes on 4 other tables..

```
try {
        LOG.debug("Deleting customer " + customer);
        BatchStatement batch = new BatchStatement();
        batch.add(customerDeleteStmt.bind(customer.getId());
        batch.add(customerByAccountNumberDeleteStmt.bind(customer.getId(), customer.getAcctNum()));
        //3 more cleanup stmts in batch..
        batch.add(...);
        batch.add(...);
        batch.add(...);
        cassandraTemplate.execute(batch);
        LOG.info("Deleted Customer " + customer);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Exception in batched Delete.", e);
        throw new DatabaseException("Error: CustomerDAO.delete failed. Exception is: " + e.getMessage());
```

## }

UPDATE: 
**This doesn't seem like a delete issue as I suspected initially.**
Upon investigation it turned out that batched delete worked as expected. What caused the anomaly in this table was an update(After the batched delete for the same row) that was trying to update one column with empty string(not null)..In this case cassandra was issuing an insert (instead of what we thought to be no-op) resulting in a new row with null values for non-key columns and empty value to the updated column.

Changed the code to set the column value to be null in update statement, and it fixed our issue.

## Please advise how I can mark this as a non-issue/resolved (whichever is appropriate).

thanks.

Comment: Describe this table please.

Comment: And the statements in use, the whole batch if possible

Comment: I didn't ask your PRIMARY KEY, I asked you to post the `DESCRIBE mytable;` command output from `cqlsh`.

Comment: hey xmas79, updated the table definition in the question above.